# installation of floor safe

Tags: framing

~floor safe ~ 24"width X 19"depth @350 lbs, including contents
~ position ~ centered @ 30" (12" either side of this point) from outside concrete
            foundation wall, the 19" depth is sitting 1/3 over a joist 2/3 over 
            plywood sub floor
          ~ the 24" width will be parallel with the direction of the floor joist
            underneath
          ~ floor composition ~ 5/8 plywood over 2"X10"X 14" spruce joist 16" on 
                               center.
Is additional joist reinforcement required ??

Comment: your description is cryptic ... either use proper English sentence structure or draw a diagram

Comment: A clearly drawn diagram would be the overall best additional communication here.